# JSP javascript alert doesn't display inside java method

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have the following code snippet in my JSP file:

```
if ( action != null && action.equals( "newRow" ) ) {
    try {
        if(tblMgr.isRowInDueCauseTable(reason, task, result, resultCause)) {
%>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert('Parameters already exists');
            </script>
<%
        } else {
            tblMgr.insertItem(tmpB.toString());
        }
    } catch (BusinessException bex) {
        trace ( "BusinessException: modifyEntity() - " + bex.getErrCode ( ) );
        addErrorMessage ( bex, session );
        strDoMsgFrameReload=DO_MSG_FRAME_RELOAD;
    }
```

The java method runs as expected, the main logic is that it only let's inserting a new row into database, if it isn't already there with the same values. And it works properly, doesn't let me insert a row with existing values, but if I try to insert a same row, the alert message isn't appearing on the page. I'm not familiar with javascript. There is a main jsp file, which has defined everything needed to use javascript, because other alert() functions are displayed correctly. Are the script tags unnecessary? They are already defined on the main jsp page. Or shall I insert this into a function?

Comment: Does the tblMgr.isRowInDueCauseTable method work as expected?

Comment: yes, it does. only the alert doesn't appear